# Converting an Ascii string to bit stream

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, microcontroller, 8051

I am doing a project in which i am getting data from some switches and push buttons on the pins of 8051 MC. Now i have to transmit serially, this data on the port pins, to the PC. At the PC end i am receiving the data in C# sharp .net application using the serial port class. Now the issue is that I want that the data received in C sharp application is in the form of bit string instead of Ascii.

Can someone guide me how it can be achieved ?

Comment: you can start by showing us the code that accepts the data, sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Ilia The thing is that there is obviously some combinations of 1's and 0's on the port. When i take this combination of 8 bits data from the port and transmit it to the PC i get some random symbols. Instead i want it to be exactly the same combination bit string i.e. combination 8 bits as it was on the port of 8051 .

Comment: My code for serially receiving the data from 8051 Micro controller is:-    private void serialPortRead_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) { try { Rxstring = serialPortRead.ReadExisting(); /*Rxstring has string data type*/ this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText)); } catch (System.TimeoutException) { } } private void DisplayText(object s, EventArgs e) { ReadTextBox.AppendText(Rxstring); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
byte b = 23;
var str = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Characters are typically stored in sets of double bytes in C#. So for each 16 bits, cast the set of the binary to type char.

```
char c = (char)myBinary;
```

Edit: This of course depends on how many bits your project allocates to each character. It is likely it is a single byte. If this is so you will need to look into the link below for character structure.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9h8tsay.aspx